# How to fix broken python installation causng Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)?

Tags: 18.04, apt, dpkg, python3, default

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-venv is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  blt fonts-dejavu icc-profiles-free libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkspell0
  libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl libmagick++-6.q16-7 libmysqlclient20 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libpodofo0.9.5 libpotrace0
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-dev libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-sql
  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libtcl8.6 libtk8.6 python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-dev
  python2.7-minimal qdbus qt-at-spi qtchooser qtcore4-l10n tk8.6-blt2.5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3.6 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.6.postinst: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.6.postinst: /usr/bin/python3.6: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure):
 installed python3.6 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.6 (>= 3.6.7-1~); however:
  Package python3.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6-venv:
 python3.6-venv depends on python3.6 (= 3.6.9-1~18.04); however:
  Package python3.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6-venv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-wheel:
 python3-wheel depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package pythoNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                         No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                   n3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pip:
 python3-pip depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-setuptools:
 python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6-dev:
 python3.6-dev depends on python3.6 (= 3.6.9-1~18.04); however:
  Package python3.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leavinNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
       g unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-venv:
 python3-venv depends on python3.6-venv (>= 3.6.7-1~); however:
  Package python3.6-venv is not configured yet.
 python3-venv depends on python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-venv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.6
 python3
 python3.6-venv
 python3-dev
 python3-wheel
 python3-pip
 python3-setuptools
 python3.6-dev
 dh-python
 python3-venv
 gnome-menus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try putting some of this into code blocks to make it easier to read.

Comment: Looks like you unwisely tried to install multiple versions of Python3 (3.3 and 3.6) using apt instead of, so a seriously damaged system is expected behavior. Download python3-minimal and python3 for 18.04 from http://packages.ubuntu.com and use dpkg to install them. If that fails, then back up your data and clean-install.